# get the name of ckEditor instance

Tags: ckeditor

I have three ckEditor instances in my page say a,b,c.Now on click of the image upload button I need to check from which one of a,b,c image upload is getting called.i.e I need the name of the ckEditor instance.

Answer (score 0):

"editor" object has a property "name", you can make use of that.